# Overflowing content in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want my Navbar breakpoint after it comes from large to 
medium screens. Could anyone explain to me how to exactly do so in code?

This is mentioned on bootstrap site on Overflowing Content

> Since Bootstrap doesn't know how much space the content in your navbar needs, you might run into issues with content wrapping into a second row. To resolve this, you can:
>
> 1. Reduce the amount or width of navbar items.
>      Hide certain navbar items at certain screen sizes using responsive utility classes.
> 2. Change the point at which your navbar switches between collapsed and horizontal mode. Customize the `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable or add your own media query.

This is mentioned on Bootstrap for mobile navbar breakpoint

> Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint. The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than `@grid-float-breakpoint`, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least `@grid-float-breakpoint` in width. Adjust this variable in the `Less` source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

Comment: It's talking about downloading the Bootstrap `less` or `sass` source code (which is available on the site), editing the entry in `variables.less` for `@grid-float-breakpoint` to whatever the breakpoint is for medium screens, then recompiling the `.css` and `.js` files using a `less` or `sass` compiler.